# Installing ffmpeg (namely fdk-aac) on cPanel server causes issues with perl threads

Tags: ffmpeg, perl, threads

Basically, I'm trying to install FFMPEG on a cPanel server.  I'm able to get everything installed and working (tested using `ffmpeg -v`) except for libfdk-aac.  I can do the `git clone` and everything just fine, but when I try to run `autoreconf -fiv` in the fdk-aac directory I get:

```
root@matrix [~/ffmpeg-source/fdk-aac]# autoreconf -fiv
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4 --output=aclocal.m4t
/usr/share/automake-1.11/Automake/ChannelDefs.pm line 23:

This Perl hasn't been configured and built properly for the threads
module to work.  (The 'useithreads' configuration option hasn't been used.)

Having threads support requires all of Perl and all of the XS modules in
the Perl installation to be rebuilt, it is not just a question of adding
the threads module.  (In other words, threaded and non-threaded Perls
are binary incompatible.)

If you want to the use the threads module, please contact the people
who built your Perl.

Cannot continue, aborting.
```

I've tried using [Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl) to install a separate version of perl using the `-Dusethreads` and the `-Duseithreads` options, but nothing changes, same error.

The command I am using for installing using Perlbrew is: `perlbrew --force install --as perl-5.16.3-t -Dusethreads -Duseithreads perl-5.16.3`

Nothing seems to help.  Is this even possible?  Please don't tell me not to use cPanel, it's for a client and he needs it. :P

EDIT: The guide I'm using can be found here: [CentosCompilationGuide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm trying to do exactly the same thing and haven't succeeded with getting it to recognise my perlbrew version of perl. 
There's hardly any information about libfdk-aac anywhere...
I'd appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Terribly bad-practice solution, but I just solved this by following this section to build libfdk-aac on a new, clean, centos 6 virtual machine created specifically for this task:

cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
git clone --depth 1 git://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac.git
cd fdk-aac
autoreconf -fiv
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --disable-shared
make

then tarring the build folder, copying it to and extracting it on my cPanel machine, then running "make install" from inside it. That copied the library to my ffmpeg build prefix (since I kept the prefix the same when I built it on the virtual machine), so I was then able to configure and build ffmpeg properly with the fdk aac encoder.

If it's of any use, here is the tar archive of my libfdk-aac build, as described above, with the prefix set to ~/ffmpeg-build from the root account, therefore when "make install" is executed, it will copy the fdk aac library to /root/ffmpeg-build.

It should work fine for you, if you followed the entire Centos Compilation Guide from the root account. Let me know how it goes!

http://andrewbeveridge.co.uk/old/fdk-aac.tar.gz

UPDATE:

Actually, I just found centos rpms for fdk-aac, so installing these is probably an easier and better way to get ffmpeg to compile on a cPanel system, assuming it is 64 bit.

```
rpm -Uvh http://andrewbeveridge.co.uk/old/fdk-aac-0.1.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm http://andrewbeveridge.co.uk/old/fdk-aac-devel-0.1.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```